# Inject jQuery into the current tab page - chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extensions, so I maybe using the wrong terms.

I have created a extension

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Run code in page",
    "version": "1.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["contentscript.js"],
        "matches": ["https://*/*"]
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["*.js"],
    "default_locale": "en"
}
```

**contentscript.js**

```
function injectScript(script) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = chrome.extension.getURL(script);
    (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
}

injectScript('script.js');
injectScript('otherscript.js');
```

**script.js**

```
console.log('script.js');
```

**otherscript.js**

```
console.log('otherscript.js');
```

This works, I see this in the output :

```
script.js
otherscript.js
```

All is good, both scripts are loading, I need jQuery to be added in the same way so that I can access jQuery from my script.

So, I

```
injectScript('jquery.js');
```

But now I get the following error

```
Denying load of chrome-extension://abdiolbenneaffeaedmfeeanlephlnoo/jquery.js. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
```

If I look at the DOM, I see this

```
<script src="chrome-extension://abdiolbenneaffeaedmfeeanlephlnoo/script.js"></script>
<script src="chrome-extension://abdiolbenneaffeaedmfeeanlephlnoo/otherscript.js"></script>
<script src="chrome-extension://abdiolbenneaffeaedmfeeanlephlnoo/jquery.js"></script>
```

If I put chrome-extension://abdiolbenneaffeaedmfeeanlephlnoo/jquery.js into the URL I can access it.

-- edit

If I load jquery externally it will load, so I guess I can just do that. eg

```
function injectExternalScript(script) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = script;
    (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
}

injectExternalScript('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want do inject jQuery into your extensions background page do in inside the `manifest.json` like so:

**Example:**

```
"background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["jquery-3.3.1.min.js", "background.js"]
},
```

*Note*: Make sure jQuery is first in the array so it loads before the actual `background.js`

---

**But,** in your case, you are not executing that code in the background nor are you injecting anything to it since you are mistaking a content script for a background page which you **don't have**.

I recommend you first read the official documentation regarding [Chrome Extension Architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) before anything else.

---

You can also write code like so in your `content.js` to be injected directly into the DOM from your content script so you can avoid using multiple unnecessary `.js` files in your extension.

**Content.js:**

```
//Injects functions directly into the dom
function inject(fn) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("type", "application/javascript");
    script.textContent = '(' + fn + ')();';
    document.body.appendChild(script); // run the script
    document.body.removeChild(script); // clean up
}

inject(function(){
    // code that will be executed in the scope of the page
}
```

You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/6586663).

Comment: thanks, I did something like this, it worked for all scripts except jQuery, but just telling it to load jQuery from the CDN worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is really weird. You probably checked if the `jquery.js` file is in the root folder and with this name, right?

Well, in my case I wanted to add jQuery in all pages that match in `content_scripts > matches` so I just did something like this:

```
...
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "https://*/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "assets/js/jquery.js",
            "assets/js/contentscript.js"
        ]
    }
],
...
```

So in this way I can use jQuery in `contentscript.js` file.

Comment: I have triple checked, but I will check again. I tend to `copy` the filename via the F2 rename option. And, if I follow the link in the `cannot download error` I do get the file.

Comment: That is so weird! Can't imagine why this occurs.